# How can I turn off indexing in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: xcode

Xcode tends to spend a lot of time indexing and being really slow for my project, so I'd like to turn it off. There doesn't seem to be an option in the menus and I've tried

```
> defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

Xcode 5.1.1 still seems to go through the loading index step though.