# Xcode 5.1 constantly indexing cmake generated project

Tags: xcode, cmake, xcode5

I generated an Xcode C++ project using the `cmake -GXcode` generator, and it works great — except that Xcode is constantly indexing the project.

I've tried regenerating it from scratch.

I've also tried `defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1`, which works for Xcode 4, but [seems to have no effect on Xcode 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023101/how-can-i-turn-off-indexing-in-xcode-5-1-1).

If I forget to save (or build) for a while, it may eventually finish indexing. But I hit the save shortcut key combination almost compulsively while editing, and saving less frequently is not a great way to avoid this. Obviously, building is unavoidable.

It's slowing down my system and making everything borderline unusable. Any tips would be appreciated.